# Can't get away from UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Tags: python, python-2.7

**To read one character from the keyboard I use the following python-code**

```
def getch():
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
try:
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
return ch
```

**The following error appears all the time:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Adafruit-Motor-Hat-Python-Library/examples/Testje.py", line 36, in <module>
    char = getch()
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit-Motor-Hat-Python-Library/examples/Testje.py", line 17, in getch
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

I have searches the internet for a solution, but i can't find one. Perhaps somebody can help me.

Comment: Hmm, hard to know because you say nothing of your work environment. But Python GUI shells (at least IDLE) redirect `sys.stdin` to a socket wrapper, that does not define the `fileno()` method. How do you run above code?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I'am running this program as a test in IDLE. As you noticed i'am a newby in Python programming.

Comment: I worked running from the Command line, thanks for the tip